# allowing the user to add data into a list

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to build a contact managers program using a list to store and display the data. I need to view a report that displays a summary of contacts available and then have a menu to allow the user to interact with the program. I have a method to create a list with data but I need to change the method to allow the user to create a new contact which will contain their first and last name, phone number, email address and type. but I am not sure as to how to do this.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        //Declare the list

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();           

        Console.WriteLine("Contact List");
        // display the menu to the user
        Console.WriteLine("Enter option or M for menu:");
        //Main Driver
        char menuItem;
        menuItem = GetMenuItem();
        while (menuItem != 'X')
        {

            ProcessMenuItem(menuItem);
            menuItem = GetMenuItem();

        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, goodbye");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static char GetMenuItem()
    {
        char menuItem;
        DisplayMenu();
        menuItem = IOConsole.GetChar((Console.ReadLine()));

        while (menuItem != 'C'
            && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'X' && menuItem != 'R' && menuItem != 'U' && menuItem != 'D')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
            DisplayMenu();
            //menuItem = IOConsole.GetChar((Console.ReadLine()));
        }
        return menuItem;
    }

    static void DisplayMenu()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("C-> Create Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("R-> Remove Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("U-> Update Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("D -> Load data from file");
       Console.WriteLine("S-> Save data to file");
       Console.WriteLine("L-> View sorted by last name");
       Console.WriteLine("F-> View sorted by first name");
       Console.WriteLine("P-> View by partial name search");
       Console.WriteLine("T-> View by contact type");
       Console.WriteLine("Q-> Quit");
    }

    //Routes to the appropriate process routine based on the user menu choice
    static void ProcessMenuItem(Char menuItem)
    {
        switch (menuItem)
        {
            case 'C':
                createContact();
                break;
            case 'R':
                removeContact();
                break;
            case 'U':
                updateContact();
                break;
            case 'D':
                LoadToFile();
                break;
            case 'S':
                saveToFile();
                break;

            case 'L':
                sortByLastName();
                break;
            case 'F':
                sortByFirstName();
                   break;
            case 'P':

                   break;
            case 'T':

                   break;
            case 'Q':

                   break;

        }                   
    }

     public static void createContact()
    {
        Contact c1      = new Contact();
        //c1.Number       = 1; //Id?
        c1.GetLastName     = "Doe";
        c1.GetFirstName    = "John";
        c1.GetEmailAddress = "johndoe@email.com";
        c1.GetPhoneNumber  = "12345678";
        c1.ContactTypes         = ContactTypesEnum.Friend;

        //Create more contacts...

        //Add all contacts here
        ContactCollection contactList = new ContactCollection();
        contactList.Add(c1);

        //Loop through list
        foreach( Contact c in contactList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.GetFirstName); //Do something with fields
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: from your console app?

Comment: is cotactlist the same list having all the contacts? or are you saving them somewhere?

Comment: because as you are creating new list everytime it will create a new list everytime you come to the method. so save before thsi list values somewhere before the method ends

Comment: Prompt the user for each of the Contact properties and then read them in as Strings. Use Console.ReadLine(); and then add them to the contact list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ask user for each field

```
 public static void createContact()
        {
            Contact c1 = new Contact();
            Console.WriteLine("GetFirstName");
            c1.GetFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("GetLastName");
            c1.GetLastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("GetEmailAddress");
            c1.GetEmailAddress = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("GetPhoneNumber");
            c1.GetPhoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ContactTypes");
            c1.ContactTypes = Console.ReadLine();

            //Create more contacts...

            //Add all contacts here
            ContactCollection contactList = new ContactCollection();
            contactList.Add(c1);

            //Loop through list
            foreach (Contact c in contactList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.GetFirstName); //Do something with fields
                // Save using this foreach loop to some collection where you are storing contacts or may be directly save the list.
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

but i doubt how could you have all contact in that list because everytime it will come to this method it will create an emoty list.

Comment: Yes, he should specify his ContactCollection contactList = new ContactCollection(); at the start of his main class and it'd probably work though :)

Comment: yes exactly that's what I mean, and the example I have given is for prompting user to enter the fields values and save that he wants to enter.